# Attach a file from a form in PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, phpmailer

I'm having real issues getting a file uploaded through the PHPMailer form to attach to the email sent through gmail TLS. Can anyone help? I'm not a developer.

I can send a random file from a path, but I can't get the uploaded file through the form to attach. I think it might be because I'm setting the moving file part wrong. so no path exists?

Many thanks

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var contactForm = document.getElementById('frmContact');
    var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/blocks/sendmessage_recruit.php';
    if (contactForm) {
        contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var mailStatusEl = document.getElementById('mail-status');
            var sendMessageEl = document.getElementById('send-message');
            var loaderIconEl = document.getElementById('loader-icon');
            mailStatusEl.style.display = "none";
            sendMessageEl.style.display = "none";
            loaderIconEl.style.display = "block";
            var name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
            var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
            var phone = document.querySelector('input[name="phone"]').value;
            var content = document.querySelector('textarea[name="content"]').value;
            var userfile = document.querySelector('input[name="userfile"]').value;
            // var recaptcha = document.querySelector('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').value;
            var data = {
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "phone": phone,
                "content": content,
                "userfile": userfile,
                // "g-recaptcha-response": recaptcha
            };
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                mailStatusEl.style.display = "block";
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        loaderIconEl.style.display = "none";
                        var responseData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        if (responseData.type == 'error') {
                            sendMessageEl.style.display = "block";
                            mailStatusEl.className += " error";
                        } else {
                            sendMessageEl.style.display = "none";
                            mailStatusEl.className += " success";
                        }
                        mailStatusEl.innerHTML= responseData.text;
                    } else {
                        sendMessageEl.style.display = "block";
                        mailStatusEl.className += " error";                        
                        mailStatusEl.innerHTML = "Oh no! Something went wrong! Get in touch with us at info@northwindhealthcare.com";
                    }
                }
            }
            var formData = new FormData();
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => formData.append(key, data[key]));
            xhttp.open("POST", templateUrl, true);
            xhttp.send(formData);
        });
    }  
    });
</script>

<div class="enquiryform">
    <h2 class="enquiryform__title">Tell us about yourself and your current training (if any)</h2>
    <p>Please include as much relevant detail and experience as you can in the required fields.</p>

    <form id="frmContact" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" title="Please enter your name" class="required field__input" required>
            <label class="field__label">Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">         
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Please enter your email address" class="required email field__input" required>
            <label class="field__label">Email:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">         
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" title="Please enter your contact number" class="required phone field__input" required>
            <label class="field__label">Contact number:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="textarea">         
            <textarea id="comment-content" class="required" name="content" rows="4" class="field__input"></textarea>          
            <label for="comment-content" class="field__label" id="addmessage">Tell us about you</label>
        </div>
        
        <hr>
        <h3 class="brand sans heavy"><i class="fa-solid fa-upload"></i> Upload your CV</h3>
        <p class="small-font-size">Please upload a copy of your CV (pdf,doc,docx)</p>
        <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="mail-status" class="enquiryform__mail-status"></div>      
        <p id="loader-icon"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Sending</p>
        <button type="Submit" id="send-message" class="button button--small button--solid">Submit</button>
        
    </form>
</div>
```

And the send message operator

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/OAuth.php';

//Don't run this unless we're handling a form submission
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);


    //Commenting out to work on live. Consider testing on Digital Ocean after move
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '587';
    $mail->isHTML();
    $mail->Username = '#########';
    $mail->Password = '########';

    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_phone     = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $content        = filter_var($_POST["content"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($user_name)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Name</b>";       
    }
    if(empty($user_email)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Email</b>";
    }
    if(empty($user_phone)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Contact number</b>";
    }  
    if(empty($content)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Message</b>";
    }
    if(!empty($empty)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' Required!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Use a fixed address in your own domain as the from address
    //**DO NOT** use the submitter's address here as it will be forgery
    //and will cause your messages to fail SPF checks
    $mail->setFrom('#######', '######');
    //Send the message to yourself, or whoever should receive contact for submissions
    $mail->addAddress('#######', '######');
    //Put the submitter's address in a reply-to header
    //This will fail if the address provided is invalid,
    //in which case we should ignore the whole request
   

    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
    }

    

    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$user_email.'</b> is an invalid Email, please correct it.'));
        die($output);
    }



    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = '##### | RECRUIT enquiry from ' . $user_name;
        //Keep it simple - don't use HTML
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        // Build a simple message body and it must have no spaces, indents or tabs before each line!! Or it breaks!!
$mail->Body = <<<EOT
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Contact Number: {$_POST['phone']}
Name: {$_POST['name']}
Message: {$_POST['content']}
EOT;

    
        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email,'));
            die($output);
        } else {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .', thank you for the message. We will get back to you shortly.'));
        die($output);
        }
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Invalid email, please contact'.SENDER_EMAIL));
        die($output);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: There's a bit too much code to see what's amiss here, but I'd suggest comparing what you're doing with the simpler [file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: Is it failing to attach the file to the email, or failing to upload the file from the browser to PHP in the first place? Please do some debugging and narrow down the problem

Comment: `var userfile = document.querySelector('input[name="userfile"]').value;` looks wrong. To get the file(s) from a file input element you should have to use the `.files` property, not `.value`. It's an array so if you just know you want one file, use `.files[0]`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#getting_information_on_selected_files, and there are tons of examples online of how to upload a file using JavaScript/XHR/FormData

Comment: @ADyson that was it! I spent a long time faffing with the operator, even though everything felt correct. The JS part I wrote myself was the weak part. I changed that line to this and it worked. Big thanks.

`var userfile = document.querySelector('input[name="userfile"]').files[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
var userfile = document.querySelector('input[name="userfile"]').value;
```

is the problem. To get the file(s) from a file input element you have to use the `files` property, not `value`.

It's an array so if you just know you want one file, use `files[0]`.

```
var userfile = document.querySelector('input[name="userfile"]').files[0];
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#getting_information_on_selected_files